# How do I show that $S^1$ is the suspension of $S^0$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

How do I show that $S^1$ is the suspension of $S^0$?

I have all the definitions here, I'm just bad at applying them.
The suspension of a topological space $X$ is the quotient $CX / (X × ${$1$}$)$, where $CX$ is the cone on $X$, the quotient space $(X × [0, 1])/(X × ${$0$}$)$.

Comment: Indeed, the key advice is «draw something». It is hard *not* to be able to see this if you draw it!

Comment: Let $S^0 = \{a,b\}$ so you don't get confused with all the $0$'s and $1$'s running around. What you wrote is not correct. Also, you can't do this by breaking $S^0$ up into its two pieces and doing the construction on each; the construction inherently has all of $X \times \{1\}$ quotiented out ("crushed to a point"), and all of $X \times \{0\}$ quotiented out.

Comment: maybe you'll find this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636155/proof-check-suggestion-the-suspension-of-sn interesting

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be helpful for you to draw a picture yourself, then write a proof. If you cannot do it after you draw the picture, I am sure others will be happy to help you with the proof writing process. By the way, your definition of suspension is not (but equivalent to) the usual one.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience let $0$ and $1$ be the two points of $S^0$. Then the suspension of $S^0$ is the union of two line segments $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ ($0 \le y \le 1$) in the plane, where $\{(0,0)\}$ is identified with $\{(1,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1)\}$ is identified with $\{(1,1)\}$. This is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: You can view the suspension $SX$ of $X$ as the quotient space of $X \times [0,1]$ obtained by collapsing $X \times \{0\}$ to a point and $X \times \{1\}$ to a point. With $X = S^0 = \{0,1\}$, $X \times [0,1]$ is the set of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x = 0$ or $1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$. This is the union of the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. So $SX$ is obtained from the union of these segments by identifying $\{(0,0)\}$ with $\{(1,0)\}$ and $\{(0,1)\}$ with $\{(1,1)\}$.

Comment: Now imagine bending the line segments into circular arcs, and using the identifications, merge them together. The result is a circle.

Comment: See if you can now convince yourself that $\Sigma S^1\cong S^2$.