# Proof check/ suggestion: The suspension of $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

In one of my excercise sheets there was a remark saying that $$SX \approx S^{n+1}$$

where $SX$ denotes the suspension of $X=S^n$. So I tried to prove this on my own and would like to discuss my attempt and see what can be done better or where one should be more precise. This is a very troubling and difficult thing for me in algebraic topology so don't hesitate to point out these things as I'm eager to improve on this.

**Proof:**

Define the map $F: S^n \times [-1,1] \to S^{n+1}$ by $(\vec{x},t) \mapsto (r(t)\vec{x},t)$ where $r: [-1,1] \to [0,1]$ is the scalar function which gives us the radius of the lattitude of $S^{n+1}$ at $(0,...,0,t)$.

Since $r$ is continuous it follows that $F$ is continuous. Now observe that:

$$F(\vec{x},1)=(r(1)\vec{x},1)=(0\vec{x},1)=(0,1) (\forall x \in S^n)$$
$$F(\vec{x},-1)=(r(-1)\vec{x},0)=(0\vec{x},0)=(0,0) (\forall x \in S^n)$$

as at $t=-1,1$ we are at the south/north-pole of the $S^{n+1}$ sphere. With this observation we can deduce that $F$ descends to a well defined map 
$$\tilde{F}: S^n\times [-1,1]/ \tilde{} \to S^{n+1}$$

where $\tilde{}$ denotes the equivalence of $(\vec{x},-1) \tilde{} (\vec{x}',-1)$ and $(\vec{x},1) \tilde{} (\vec{x}',1)$ for any $\vec{x},\vec{x}' \in S^n$. Since $F$ is continuous we know by the universal property of final topologies that so is $\tilde{F}$.

It's easy to see that $\tilde{F}$ is bijective and since $S^n \times [-1,1]/ \tilde{}$ is compact and $S^{n+1}$ is Hausdorff we conclude that $\tilde{F}$ is a homeomorphism and hence $SX \approx S^{n+1}$ since $(S^n \times [-1,1])/ \tilde{} \approx (S^n \times [0,1])/ \tilde{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the point $(r(t)x, t)$ is to lie on $S^{n+1}$, then $r(t)^2 + t^2 = 1$, so, since $r(t)$ is non-negative, one must have $r(t) = \sqrt{1 - t^2}$. But this function does not satisfy $r(0) = 0$. The way to fix this is consider $I = [-1,1]$ instead, and carry the proof as you did, just changing $0$ and $1$ to $-1$ and $1$, respectively. Of course, the resulting quotient space $(S^n \times [-1,1])/ \tilde{}$ will be homeomorphic to the suspension $(S^n \times [0,1])/ \tilde{}$.

Comment: yes you are right! Thanks! I'm going to edit it.

Comment: is it fine like this?